# No Wordpress Styles

Tags: wordpress

Recently installed Wordpress on my website and on my first time visiting the new install, I noticed that there was absolutely no styling whatsoever. I have included an image below just to show what I mean.

How would I go about fixing this? I have tried clearing my cache and all that but I doubt that would do anything since this was my first time visiting the page.

[image: Wordpress Install]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised it was due to the fact that I had a domain change. When I inspected the page I noticed that none of the links had been updated so I needed to do a fresh install.